# How to clear data from activity using device back button

Tags: android, button, android-activity, reload

I had created an android app which has 3 activity (A,B,C) in activity A there is 2 autocomplete `textview` which fetch data from database and button after selecting  data in autocomplete text user press button and it goes to next activity which show `listview`.

Now the problem is when I press the devices back button from `listview` is display activity A with selected data in autotext how can I avoid the selected data when I press device back button.

Thanks for helping in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you press the back button, activity A will "resume".  So, in your Activity A override "onResume"...in the onResume method, clear your fields.

Comment: what if the activiy is paused due to other reason like home button pressed. in that case your solution will fail

Comment: How so?  The onResume is part of the lifecycle of the app.  If you press Home then return to the activity, if it can be resumed it will resume; if it isn't then it will be created then onStart then onResume.  I understood the basic question to be, "how to clear the data whenever the screen becomes visible."

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing with the listactivity's  back button as you are trying to clear you field in the previous activity. As you are not finishing your previous activity while creating the list activity so the previous activity is not changing. So while you are returing from the list you are saying the same data as before. to do so as @Dave suggested you could have done the clearing in the oResume method or onPause method. But there is a problem. If you clear your data in onResume or in onPause you data will be cleared for other pausing or resuming reasons like pressing home, or for other applications etc. So you can do any of two

**Option 1:**

clear the data of the previous activity when you are starting the list activity

or

**Option 2:**

instead of `startActivity` call `startActiviyForResult` and also override `onActiviyResult` method. So there you can detect when you are returning from list activity. Then clear the data.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I thought the OP wanted to clear each time the activity resumes.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this problem, I would simply override onBackPressed() method, and in there, I would have cleared activity stack as there is no logical explanation to keep activities in memory, and then start a fresh intent to your original activity.
Here is code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_A.class);      //I suppose they are in same package

     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(intent);

}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

this also works well..

Answer (score 0):

you should implement startActivityforResut
When you come back to this activity on result you can clear the data